# $().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems

Tags: spservices

is it possible to use camlQueryOtions like

```
var camlQueryOptions = "<QueryOptions><Folder>" + searchfolderName + "</Folder></QueryOptions>";
```

with  $().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems ?

I want to update some values in a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `CAMLQueryOptions` could not be specified for SPUpdateMultipleListItems operation, in my case this parameter is ignored.

But you could specify the following CAML query that allows to restrict update operation to a specific folder using `CAMLQuery` parameter:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/{web}/{list}/{folder}</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

**Working example**

The following example demonstrates how to set `DocumentStatus` field value to `Open`only for documents located under folder named `Orders` (url: `/News/Shared Documents/Orders`):

```
$().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems({
  listName: "Documents",
  CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/News/Shared Documents/Orders</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
  valuepairs: [["DocumentStatus", "Open"]]
});
```